# Laurent-Development of zero function

Tags: laurent-series

> > The following "idendity" contradicts the uniqueness of the Laurent Development:
> >     $$
> > 0=\frac{1}{z-1}+\frac{1}{1-z}=\frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{1-1/z}+\frac{1}{1-z}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{z^n}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}z^n
> > $$
> >     1) Where is the mistake? 2) When does $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}z^n$ converge?

My answers are:

1)

The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{z^n}$ converges for $\lvert z\rvert >1$.

The series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n$ converges fpr $\lvert z\rvert <1$.

So the mistake is to develop both fractions in a geometric series, because this does not work!

2)

The negative degree power series of the Laurentseries converges for $\lvert z\rvert>1$, the positive degree power series converges for $\lvert z\rvert < 1$. So the whole Laurentseries converges for
$$
\left\{z\in\mathbb{C}: 1<\lvert z\rvert <1\right\}=\emptyset.
$$

So the Laurentseries never converges?

Comment: Your answers are correct I believe.

Comment: To your sentence "So the mistake is to develop both fractions in a geometric series, because this does not work!" I would suggest adding "at the same time". You can develop both $\frac{1}{1-1/z}$ and $\frac{1}{1-z}$ in geometric series, but not for the same $z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. The series $\delta(z) = \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty z^n$ does not converge anywhere (so there is no contradiction -- to get uniqueness for a Laurent series expansion you need convergence on an open annulus ).

Now even though this series $\delta(z)$ does not converge anywhere, it is tremendously useful in formal series manipulations. It even has a name: *the formal Dirac delta*. It is an example of an *expansion of zero* (since it would be an alternate Laurent series expansion of zero *if* it converged).

Expansions of zero and especially the formal delta function play a significant role in the theory of [vertex algebras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_algebra). For more details, James Lepowsky and Haisheng Li's text  "Introduction To Vertex Operator Algebras And Their Representations" is a great reference.

Comment: When $z=0$ - does the series converge?

Comment: Not unless $0^{-1}$ is ok with you. :)

Comment: It's not defined...

Comment: Exactly, you can't plug in zero, so it doesn't converge there -- it's not even **defined** at zero!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am happy that I was right and to get additional information from you.

Comment: Glad to help. :)